# I want to add all the values that user inputted in the loop together to let the use know what their total sum is

Tags: java, loops

I want to make a code that asks the user for different values and then adds them all up together. The sum would then be displayed to them to see. I have so far been able to make a loop where it make multiple text boxes, the amount of text boxes depends on the number of values they want to add. But I do not know how to add up all their values and display it for them.

```
 Scanner myInput = new Scanner(System.in);

 int addNumber, total;
 int num = 0;

 System.out.println("Please input how many values you wish to add up together");
 addNumber = myInput.nextInt();

  for (int numValue =1; numValue <= addNumber; numValue++)
  {
    int value;
    total = num + numValue;

    System.out.println("Please input your " + total + " value.");
    value = myInput.nextInt(); 
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are almost there

First of all initialise `total`

```
int total = 0;

for (int numValue =1; numValue <= addNumber; numValue++)
  {

    System.out.println("Please input your " + numValue + " value.");
    total += myInput.nextInt(); 
  }

System.out.println ("The total is " + total);
```

In this code

```
total = num + numValue;
```

you are simply setting the value of `total` to `numValue` as `num` is always `0`

In my code I am using `total` to store the final answer, by adding the entered value to the running total